# How do I create a animation for my button in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

upon searching for some material design I came across this button from
this page: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/art/Material5.gif.

So this strikes my curiosity as how can I achieves the same button animation as the one shown in an android app?

I have search it on google but no results were really found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your solution in this article to animating the icon to toggle between two states.
The FAB that contains a plus symbol which is created using a `VectorDrawable`. The `FAB` toggle  between two states, and animate between the `‘plus’` symbol and a `‘minus’` symbol. You can replace `‘minus’` symbol with your `'tick'` symbol.

Here is the link to article:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/floating-action-button-part-2/

Here is the link to source code:
https://bitbucket.org/StylingAndroid/floatingactionbutton/src/84153529d82ccbab1c6a11d971c03a165d0440ee/?at=Part2